# Jquery using checkbox to change dropdown by class not name

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu

I want to update all dropdowns by clicking on checkbox. I'm using foreach to get all the selected checkboxes.

This will update all on the page but I want to accomplish this using the class name not the field name

```
$('select[name=order_status] option[value=1]').attr('selected', 'selected');
```

I want something like this ".shipping_'+do_csv+'

```
$('.option_completed').click(function() {
    var do_csv = [];
    $("input[name='options[]']:checked").each(function() {
        do_csv.push($(this).val());
        $(".shipping_'+do_csv+' option[value=1]").attr('selected', 'selected');
    });
});
```

Comment: What are the classnames for your dropdowns?

Comment: .shipping_'+do_csv+'  gets it value from the checkbox the class could be .shipping_1 or  .shipping_3432 depending on the order id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace this:

```
$(".shipping_'+do_csv+' option[value=1]").attr('selected', 'selected');
```

with that:

```
$(".shipping_"+$(this).val()+" option[value=1]").attr('selected', 'selected');
```

Answer (score 1):

If your class names are `shipping_somethinghere` and `dp_csv` is an array of `somethinghere`'s, then I think this is what you're looking for:

```
$.each(do_csv, function(i, val) {
    $(".shipping_" + val + " option[value=1]").attr('selected', 'selected');
}
```